# SQL Session state server in own database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've made a website and uploaded it to my hosting-server (some smalltime hosting provider). It runs great but there is a problem with the Session; It keeps logging out my user.

It happens on complete random, so I phoned the provider to ask what kind of server my website is hosted in. They told me it was a shared hosting IIS farm. So what is happening is that the loadbalancer is re-routing my session to another server, so my session is lost and I get a login screen.

To solve this I need to use a Session State Service or SQL Session State database.

The provider said there is no way to run a dedicated Session State Service in the server-farm, so that leaves me with the SQL Session State database option.

For this I need to run the "aspnet_regsql" tool on my SQL Server, but when I do this I get this error:

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET SQL Registration Tool version 4.0.30319.33440
Administrative utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET features on a SQL server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Start adding session state.

.
An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallSqlState.sql'. The SQL error number is 262 and the SqlException message is: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
SQL Server: ................
Database: aspnetdb
SQL file loaded:
InstallSqlState.sql

Commands failed:

/* Create and populate the session state database */

IF DB_ID(N'ASPState') IS NULL BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(500)
    SET @cmd = N'CREATE DATABASE [ASPState]'
    EXEC(@cmd)
    END

    SQL Exception:
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.ExecuteFile(String file, String server, String database, String dbFileName, SqlConnection connection, Boolean sessionState, Boolean isInstall, SessionStateType sessionStatetype)
    ClientConnectionId:............................................
    Error Number:262,State:1,Class:14
```

So I don't have permissions to create my own database, so there is no way to create the Dedicated "ASPState" database.

Can anyone help? Is there a way to maybe install the SessionState service on the database that is assigned to my account, instat of a dedicated ASPState database?

Comment: If your hosting company is configured such that they cannot maintain the built in basic IIS session state, demand a refund & change hosting company.

Comment: I did Alex, thanks, I forgot all about this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use aspnet_regsql command line utility then specify connection string and database name to create tables if db name exists in server it does not create database and will create tables
[Msdn link] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx

For example command line:
aspnet_regsql -A all -C "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;" -d yourbusinessdbname

Comment: If I run the "aspnet_regsql" tool it always wants to create the tables in a separate "ASPState" database. But my user does not have sufficient rights to create a new database, and I cannot get those rights either because it is not my sql server...